# error while running matplotlib

Tags: macos, matplotlib, x11, osx-mavericks

I have Python 2.7, NLTK and NLTK Data installed. Since I didn't know OSX 10.9 came with matplotlib and numpy, I installed matplotlib 1.2 and numpy packages. Now when I run this code in IDLE

text4.dispersion_plot(["citizen", "democracy", "freedom", "duties", "america"])

I get the error
'To open "Python," you need to install X11'.

Please help. Thanks.

- Ananya

Comment: Have you tried installing X11?

Comment: no. I am hoping if there is a way to fix this without installing X11.

Comment: X11 is usually installed by default on a mac, unless the option was unchecked at install. If you don't want to install X11 you could install XQuartz instead. You will more than likely need one of them to allow python to draw on the mac.

Comment: Aren' Xquartz and X11 same?

Comment: re-tagged is this is really a mac configuration issue.